# I tried to check if index was out of range, but the code I used is giving index out of range?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, range, sequence

I built this function to change a string input into pig latin. I was trying to check if the index was out of range but my method of checking is yielding index out of range.

See as follows:

```
def simple_pig_latin(input, sep=' ', end='.'):
    words=input.replace(" ", " ").split(sep)
    new_sentence=""
    Vowels= ('a','e','i','o','u')
    Digit= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    cons=('b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z')
    characters= ('!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','.')
    for word in words:
        if word[0] == " ":
            new_word=word
        else:   
            if word[0] in Vowels:
                new_word= word+"way"
            if word[0] in Digit:
                new_word= word
            if word[0] in cons:
                first_letter=word[0] #saves the first letter
                change= str(word) #change to string                     
                rem= change.replace(first_letter,'')
                put_last= rem+first_letter #add letter to end
                new_word= put_last+"ay"
            if word[0] in characters:
                new_word= word
            new_sentence= new_sentence+new_word+sep

new_sentence= new_sentence.strip(sep)+end
return new_sentence
```

You can see the first if statement is checking if it is empty, but I'm getting this exact error:

"line 9 IndexError: string index out of range"

How else can I check for the empty sequence? I can't use for word in range(len(words)) because then none of my if statements work. It will tell me object is not subscriptable.

Comment: "You can see the first if statement is checking if it is empty" - no it's not. It's trying to access `word[0]` and see if `word[0]` is a space. It assumes that `word[0]` exists. That is nothing like a check for if `word` is empty.

Comment: What is the reason this question was downvoted? I would like to fix my error so that it doesn't get poor votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your loop you assume that `word` is not empty, which is not guaranteed at all, because you're splitting according to *space*, and empty fields can be issued when there are more than 1 space.

```
>>> "a  b".split(" ")
['a', '', 'b']
```

So you could use `split()` without any argument (works only for space-like chars) or if you're using some other separator, filter out empty fields before your loop, for instance in a list comprehension:

```
words= [ w for w in input.split(sep) if w ]
```

Now you're sure that each item of `words` has at least 1 character.

EDIT: so much for the nice explanation about `split` and filtering out empty strings, but that doesn't seem to cut it since you can use `l` as a separator for `hello world`, so back to basics:

```
def simple_pig_latin(input, sep=' ', end='.'):
    words=input.split(sep)
    new_sentence=""
    Vowels= ('a','e','i','o','u')
    Digit= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    cons=set(('b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'))
    characters= ('!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','.')
    new_sentence = []

    for word in words:
        if word:
            if word[0] == " ":
                new_word=word
            else:
                if word[0] in Vowels:
                    new_word= word+"way"
                elif word[0] in Digit:
                    new_word= word
                elif word[0] in cons:
                    first_letter=word[0] #saves the first letter
                    change= str(word) #change to string
                    rem= change.replace(first_letter,'')
                    put_last= rem+first_letter #add letter to end
                    new_word= put_last+"ay"
                elif word[0] in characters:
                    new_word= word
                new_sentence.append(new_word)
        else:
            new_sentence.append(word)

    return sep.join(new_sentence)+end
```

changes to your code:

- use a list, and join back using `join` in the end
- just filters out empty word, but puts it in the list anyway
- a lot of `elif` instead of `if`
- using a `set` for consomns for faster lookup

now:

```
print(simple_pig_latin("hello world",sep='l'))
```

yields:

```
ehayllo worwaylday.
```

Comment: That solved the out of range error! I'm still failing this test case: AssertionError: 'ehaylo worwaylday' != 'ehayllo worwaylday' I know this has something to do with having the separator = "l". If I take away strip, I fail all test cases so how can I keep that extra l?

Comment: It tells me I cannot concatenate for that final return statement.TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: I tested that. So maybe you just retyped my solution (with a typo) rather than copying/pasting.